# activate and deactivate textInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

StackOverflow I'm trying to make a button to change the boolean value from true to false and vise versa in order to change editable value in textInput.
This is how far I got till this momment:

```
  const [change, setChange] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const textEdit = () => {
    change === true ? setChange(false) : setChange(true);

  };
```

for some reason after hitting below TouchableOpacity, it won't change the state or there must be a problem in my code that prevent react from changing the state of "change" in the below text input

```
        <TextInput
          style={{ width: "100%", height: 100, backgroundColor: "gray" }}
          placeholder={"write something"}
          onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
          editable={change}
        >
          <Text>adderess</Text>
        </TextInput>


        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            textEdit;
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "blue" }}>Change</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't call function `textEdit` on press. Just update like this:

```
onPress={() => {
  textEdit();
}}
```

Or cleaner:

```
onPress={textEdit}
```

Comment: unbelievable. 

Thanks for help it fix the issue.